# Ensuring binary packages with use-package

Tags: use-package

I just started organizing my packages with `use-package` because I need the simple transition between few computers. I use few binary programs asynchronously, and been therefor searching for solution that lets me maintain them along Emacs packages.

It seems pretty easy with use-package, but I am constantly getting errors like:

```
Error (use-package): Cannot load ag
```

I tried to supply optional installation command as second argument to the keyword `:ensure-system-package`, still error is the same for my setup.

```elisp
(use-package ag
  :ensure-system-package (ag . "wajig install ag")
  :config
  (use-package helm-ag-r :ensure t))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that all you're missing is `:ensure t` for `ag` itself:

```elisp
(use-package ag
  :ensure t
  :ensure-system-package (ag . "wajig install ag")
  :config
  (use-package helm-ag-r :ensure t))
```